# diabetes complications dataset

Tags: data-request, medical

I need a data set of diabetes patients suffering from diabetes complications like retinopathy kidney diseases and etc. dividing by patient age and sex in at least 25 years.

Answer (score 2):

[UCI Machine Learning Repository](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/) provides three datasets for diabetes:

- [Diabetes Data Set](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Diabetes)
- [Pima Indians Diabetes Dataset](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Pima+Indians+Diabetes)
- [Diabetes 130-US hospitals for years 1999-2008 Data Set](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Diabetes+130-US+hospitals+for+years+1999-2008)

If these don't meet your needs, you may want to go through the papers that cite these datasets and see what else they have used.